# Golang project Protobuf corrupted imports

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm not a golang developer but currently I have to fix code on it, so sorry in advance if I accidentally not understand some basic Go's concept ;) I have a third party `protobuf` contract which I have to use and on which I don't have influence. I'm not able to provide actual example of the contract, so I've made [similar example project on Github](https://github.com/doroshenko-viktor/go-proto-imports-problem) which has the same problem.
In short: there is a deeply nested structure of `proto` documents where some of them import others:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package company.nested1.nested2;

import "company/common.proto";

option go_package = "nested2";

message CompanyMessage {
    CompanyEnum compEnum = 1;
}
```

references

```
syntax = "proto3";

package company;

option go_package = "company";

enum CompanyEnum {
    VAR1 = 0;
    VAR2 = 1;
}
```

There is a `go.mod` file with following code:

```
module go-program

go 1.16

require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2
    golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.40.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.26.0
)
```

And when compiling to the Golang code there is a problem in this import. Generated `*.pb.go` files have imports relative to `company` package while they are used inside of a go project with root in `go-project` so these imports can't be resolved:
[image]

As I understand, previously this problem has been solved by manual editing of imports in generated files. Like in the screen below. But in my opinion there should be a better way for this ;)

[image]

I'm using this command to generate go code from proto files:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto (find proto -name '*.proto') --go_out=plugins=grpc:.
```

So the question is: what is a proper way to solve such import problem in go. Seems like imports in generated files should begin with my program root namespace. But how to achieve this - maybe some options in `protoc` command which I haven't found. I tried also to put generated files inside of `$GOPATH/src` or in `vendors` and tried to make and publish separate module - no result. Is there some proper solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more some pointers rather than a definitive answer. If I find some time tomorrow, I'll repro this to give you a definitive answer.

It is challenging. Protobufs has to find a solution for each language's package management and Go's (while IMO improved) is somewhat compounded with recent addition of Modules.

My approach my with code is to have a separate repo for the protos and generated code. If the protos change, the code is regenerated. I can either reference the generated module (!) or regenerate myself. This model keeps the protos as the definitive "source" with the timesaver of "cached" generated sources. But I'm my own 3rd-party library maintainer in this config.

So:

1. Modules are manifest locally as a directory tree whose root contains `go.mod` and `go.sum` and subsidirectories representing packages.
2. When you generate the code for the 3rd-party protos, I think it would be best to create this under their own module, either as a standalone directory or as a vendored subdirectory.
3. This module should be named to reference the 3rd party and can be created with `go mod init` and should contain the output of `protoc`
4. Modules are usually pulled from a proxy or repo but you can circumvent this (since the 3rd party isn't hosting the generated code for you) by manually adding a [`replace`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) to the `go mod` redirecting from the module path to a local path.
5. From your error, this should solve the missing module issue and with a subdirectory e.g. `company` containing that generated code, should resolve the package too.

Comment: I agree with the approach of storing the generated Go code alongside the Protobuf definitions. Go isn't the only language I've seen this pattern in. A lot of Google Maven packages my code depends on work this way too. There's a package dedicated to storing the generated code for the Protobuf messages. Other applications using the generated code don't have to generate it themselves. They use an authoritative build.

Comment: With Go, this is even more straightforward because Go libraries are published by being in GitHub repos, so you can store the source code and generated code in one single published entity. Not like Java where you have source code in a Git repo and class files in a Maven package.